# Unable to Get old Messages that are published before suscribing the Topic In Apache Kafka

Tags: java, apache, chat

How can i get all messages are published before subscribed a Topic In Kafka? I m using Kafka 2.12-2.3.0 Producer for sending message and Consumer to receive message. Actually i m building a chat application in java using Kafka. But problem is if a producer posted some message and a consumer subscribed later it wont get that messages. Please give some suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your consumer has configuration option `auto.offset.reset` (exact name depends on the SDK you are using). Set it to 1 (Earliest). This will work when you connect for the first time.

Also you can explicitly assign start offset for every partition, like: `consumer.Assign(offsets);` - exact code depends on your scenario, but assigning 0 will ensure you get the earliest.